# change mysql file format and collation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, utf8mb4

I need to apply this setting to MariaDB 5.5.
Is it safe to do it on running DB? Will it affect only new databases
or old DB in Latin1/nonUTF8 might be crashed?
Of cource I will run full backup, but just want to know about others experience.

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Comment: Nice that you're making backups in advance.

Comment: Please be sure to accept an answer to close the post and to show others the solution if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this exact thing to allow for emojis to be correctly parsed. I didn't have an issue and I did it on live (along with a backup!).

My vote, based on my experience, is to proceed.

Comment: Correct. All these setting apply to newly created tables (or for innodb* `ALTER TABLES` that result in a rebuild).

Comment: Until you rebuild the tables the encoding in any particular table, or even column, will remain as it was. As danblack says you must `ALTER` to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Note the "default-" -- This implies that nothing already in existence will be affected by it.

There is more than what you did to make Emojis possible.  See "best practice" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

As Mech implied, *existing* tables will need to be `ALTERed` if the *columns* are not already `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Also, for Barracuda, file_per_table and large_prefix to take effect on a table, you must do an `ALTER`.  When finished, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as a partial variation that changes have taken effect.  `ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO utf8mb4;` is probably the simplest.

Since you are using 5.5 or 5.6, there are more things that need fixing to handle indexing `VARCHAR(255)`; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes